# Regular Expression advice for [Alphanumeric][alphanumeric.-_@] 31 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to do a name check using regex in javascript.

1. The value can contain alphanumeric and following special characters
   ('-', '.' '_' and '@').
2. It should always start with an alphanumeric character.
3. It should not be an empty string.
4. Maximum allowed length for this parameter is 31 characters.
5. This parameter is case-insensitive.

I came up with this, but feel it's incorrect. Any advice on how to have it foolproof?

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9_@-.]{30}
```

Comment: You should further move the `-` to the end of `[A-Za-z0-9_@.-]`and dont use a fixed repetition of `30`, but 0-30 `{0,30}`

Comment: And you can change `[A-Za-z0-9_@.-]` to `[\w@.-]`

Comment: @SebastianProske - Ohr right. If I put a {30} it's only going to look for length = 30 right? I need it to match for anything below 30 as well. So.. Something like this? ^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_@.-]{0,30} And we're moving - to the last because it should not pick up a range of chars like A-Z representation?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub - So.. ^[\w][\w@.-]{0,30}

Comment: Not exactly, since `\w` == `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (note the trailling underscore)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub - Understood. So.. ^[A-Za-z0-9][\w@.-]{0,30}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are quite close, here is the corrected regex:

```
/^[a-z0-9][\w@.-]{0,30}$/i
```

I applied the folloing changes:

- Added `$` anchor to the end
- used the i-modifier for case-insensitivity
- replaced `a-zA-Z0-9_` with `\w` and moved `-` to the end of the character class
- changed fixed repetition `{30}` to `{0,30}`

See the [Regex101-Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nE6lK0/1) with some unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_@.-]{0,30}
```

- place `-` at the and of brackets, so it won't be used as a range
- allow 1-31 characters `{,30}`
- remove `+` after first character (without it you would get >31 chars)

Answer (score 1):

You can always check your patterns at www.regexr.com

- You need to escape the '-' with and backslash like this: `\-`.
- You need to remove the + in the middle part
- Change `{30}` to `{0,30}` because it doesn't need to be exactly 31 characters long
- Add \i to the end for case insensitive and remove the `A-Z` parts
- Close the pattern with `$`

Result looks like this:

```
/[a-z0-9][a-z0-9@\-._]{0,30}/i
```